# How to hide div only for corresponding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple tab where I am showing some static text and few products which are dynamically created. So by default I am showing all the products. I want to hide one products in case of tab 1, 2, 3 out of total five tabs. This is the script for the tab.

Any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.content:first-child').show();
            $('.listThumbClick').live('click', function(){
            var ind = $('.listThumbClick').index(this);
            $('.content').eq(ind).show().siblings().hide(); 
        });
        //generated product is attached inside the tab
        $('.product').appendTo('.content');
    });
</script>
```

And the html somewhat looks like this. Note: I am appending the products into the tab area

```
<div class="ppt">
    <div class="listThumbClick"></div>
    <div class="listThumbClick"></div>
    <div class="listThumbClick"></div>
    <div class="listThumbClick"></div>
    <div class="listThumbClick"></div>
</div>

<div class="tabContainer">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <img src="product image source here" title="productOne"/>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <img src="product image source here" title="productTwo"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are appending all the `.product` elements to all the `.content` elements? You will have 5 tabs with the same contents. PS: `live` method is deprecated, use `on` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's just pseudo code but firstly I would not use "." as your only selector. Maybe scope it to an element with an id.

I would also cache your $('.listThumbClick') variable so you're not fetching it on every click.

One solution would be to add a data attribute to the divs that you want to hide the product.

```
<div class="listThumbClick" data-hideproduct="true">
```

And then in your handler

```
if($(this).data("hideproduct")){
    //hide the product
}
else {
    //show the product
}
```

You can also make your hiding / showing logic a little cleaner and with less work by doing this

```
var $listThumbClicks = $(".listThumbClick");
var $content = $(".content");
$listThumbClicks.live('click', function(){
    var ind = $listThumbClicks.index(this);
    $content.hide().eq(ind).show();
});
```

I'm curious what your ultimate goal is. Do you want tabs that show only specific products? Right now you're adding all products to all tabs which is strange.

What it seems like you really want to do is append only certain products to each tab.

Comment: @awbergs--my ultimate goal would be to show different products in different tabs. The reason I am showing all the products in all the tabs and trying to hide the ones which dont belong in the specif tab is 1: the products are generated dynamically so i can not define any rule before they show up. So basically I am trying to do thins by writing a work around